# how to replace a token in an xml file with filenames in ant?

Tags: xml, ant, replace, for-loop

I have an xml file with a specific element repeated once for every item in a list. 
That list is being set in a properties file for ant.

based on the list in properties file

modules.list=a, b, c, d

I need to turn this:
`<module name=@modulename@  />` into

`<module name="a" \>`
`<module name="b" \>`
etc.,

This is driving me crazy. I tried to use the for on the list, but cannot figure out how to replace the token once for each list. Its essentially not only a replace token, but also a "generate new content" thing...
thankyou

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ant is made for controlling build systems. What you want to do is generate xml content, and the best way you can do this is an xsl transformation.

You can use the xsl transformation task of ant and pass your ant parameter and the path of your xml file to the xsl transformation.

```
<xslt in="input.xml" out="output.xml"
  style="transformation.xsl">
  <param name="modules.list" expression="a,b,c,d"/>
</xslt>
```

in xslt you can than easily split the string into a list via the `tokenize()` function and iterate the items via the `for-each` element. Inside you can then generate your items.

hope that helps

i think xsl is the right tool for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a templating engine, such as Apache Velocity. Ant isn't made for the task you are trying to apply it to, though you can trigger generation using another tool from within your overall ant script.

Or you can use XSLT, which is a transformational (rather than templating language). If you already know XSLT, then go with that. Otherwise, I think you will find that learning a templating engine is easier than learning XSLT.